# How to count the number of times a date has been changed?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have the date as dd/mm/yyyy and I want to set up a rule to count the no of time it has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the old data and the new data in diferent columns. Then you can using aggr function by data to obtain the different changes using GetPossibleCount(Data).

With more information i can help better.

Comment: do we have GetPossibleCount() in qliksense ? I am using qliksense.